# laravel advanced routing to multiple controllers

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I have in a middleware those two routes so they stay on top of all other routes

```
Route::get('{slug?}', array(
    'as' => 'homeIndex',
    'uses' => 'Modules\\Pages\\Controllers\\Pages@index'
))->where('slug', '(.*)?');


Route::get('{company?}', array(
    'as' => 'companyProfile',
    'uses' => 'Modules\\Company\\Controllers\\Profile@index'
))->where('company', '(.*)?');
```

what I'm trying to achieve is route all pages through `homeIndex` and all companies profile through `companyProfile` all on the first segment.

Is working fine for pages, but for companies profile I get 404.

It's same like facebook if you go on facebook.com/about the result is about page if you replace about with your unique name you get your profile.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook works because `about` is a route.  This works because your unique name can never be `about`.  So they look for the `about` route first, and if the segment isn't `about`, they know it's probably a unique name.

Yours is different because your app doesn't know if your first segment is a slug or a company so you need some way to tell it the difference.  If you redirected everything to a single function, then in that function did some queries or whatever you need to do to figure out if the first segment is a slug or a company name, then redirect that appropriately, it would work.

Laravel reads routes from the top to the bottom.  When you hit the route `/some-random-company`, Laravel has no idea this is a company.  All it knows is it happens to match the first route so it hits the slug route with your company.  So another solution would be to update the `where`s on your routes so Laravel has some idea if the incoming route parameter is a slug or a company and will know where to route that request to.

I'm terrible at regular expressions and I don't know how you are making slugs or if there is any rules you have setup on what a company name can or can not consist of.  What you would have to do is figure out if there is anyway where you can accurately determine if the route parameter is a slug or company.  For example, if it has one or more of `-`, it might be a slug.

Then you'd have to write a regular expression pattern to look for multiple `-` and then put that pattern into the `where` for the slug route.  Then if the route parameter is a company and it does not match that pattern which was looking for one or more of `-`, Laravel will know to match this request with the company route.

If there is nothing which you can use to determine if a string is a slug or a company, you will have to update your routes so it looks like `company/{company?}` and `slug/{slug?}` and then output your links appropriately.  This way Laravel will know for sure where to route that traffic.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution but isn't a overkill for the app to every time check where the slug belongs to?

Comment: That's up to you.  Another and possibly better solution would be to come up with better patterns on the `where` clauses on your routes.  If there is going to be some difference between a `slug` and a `company` that you can depend on, if you update that `where` to reflect that, it will work.

Comment: well the company would act as a single parameter so it will alwasy be part of segment1 and pages would be single and multiple segments. Could you give me an example how you would approach this? Your suggestion has got me lost a bit :)